# How to delete table based on timestamps in R Mysql DB?

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr, rmysql

This is my timestamp

```
q1<-Sys.time()-777000 
q1
#"2019-09-12 08:39:27 GMT"
```

This is what I am trying to do , am getting an error

```
Sys.time()
dbSendQuery(conn,"delete from anomaly_hourly_temp  where report_time>q1")
Sys.time()
dbSendQuery(conn,"delete from anomaly_hourly_temp  where report_time>q1")
```

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     could not run statement: Unknown column 'q1' in 'where clause'

Also tried this , though it does not show any error , but it does not delete any row based on timestamps

```
Sys.time()
dbSendQuery(conn,"delete from anomaly_hourly_temp  where report_time>'q1'")
Sys.time()
```

If I explicitly specify timestamp(`q1`) , it does work as given below

```
dbSendQuery(conn,"delete from anomaly_hourly_temp  where report_time>'2019-09-22 11:42:51'")
```

Comment: Remove the trailing `GMT` from `q`.

Comment: I removed GMT from my q1 as given below                                                      
q1<-Sys.time()-777000
q1<-format(q1,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') .       I am still getting the same error or did not delete the data table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you attempt to interpolate the R variable into the SQL statement but SQL reads the literal *q1* and not its underlying value. While concatenating the R variable into SQL string is a solution, it is safer, more efficient, avoids quotes, and industry best practice to run parameterization using a prepared statement with parameter binded in subsequent step:

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql <- "delete from anomaly_hourly_temp  where report_time > ?")

# BIND PARAM AND EXECUTE ACTION
dbSendQuery(conn, sql, list(q))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `paste0` to paste the query together.

```
DBI::dbSendQuery(conn, 
     paste0("delete from anomaly_hourly_temp where report_time > '", q1, "'"))
```

Similar to `paste0`, we can also use `paste`/`str_c`/`glue`/`sprintf` or other function which helps to paste the query together.